# Li:hover not encompassing entire menu button on screen resize

Tags: html, css, hover

So I seem to be having an issue with the hover feature. When my screen is full size, I can hover my mouse over a menu option and the entire background color changes. However, when I resize my screen, only a portion of the background color changes. I see this upon screen resize:

[Screen Resize Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1Y4A.png)

Here is the HTML code

```
<nav>
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html" class="currentlink">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="gettingstarted.html">Getting Started</a></li>
  <li><a href="surviveandthrive.html">How Do Plants Thrive?</a></li>
  <li><a href="problems.html">Common Problems</a></li>
  <li><a href="indoorplants.html">Great Indoor Plants</a></li>
  <li><a href="references.html">References</a></li>
</ul>
<nav>
```

And the css

```
nav {
     width: 100%;
     background: #003300;
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
     border-right: none;
}

nav ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: .5% solid #fff;
    border-right: .5% solid #ccc;
    width: 16.6667%; /* fallback for non-calc() browsers */
    width: calc(100% / 6);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav ul li:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #00b300;
    width:100%;                        
}

.currentlink {
    background: #00b300;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: All right, you use float properties, this prop change position of element: it float left and to top of container. If you want to change all background, you need to use flexbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By testing your code it appears the issue is that your list items are assigning their height based on their content. As such, when you resize your window, forcing the text in one or more of your list items to wrap, the list items with the wrapped text grow taller than those with less or no wrapped text.

One possible solution, depending on how you wish to style your nav, is to utilize CSS' `flex` styling. For your CSS, try the following:

```
nav {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: none;
}
nav ul {
  background: #003300;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
}
nav ul li {
  border-left: .5% solid #fff;
  border-right: .5% solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 16.6667%;
  /* fallback for non-calc() browsers */
  width: calc(100% / 6);
}
nav ul li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #00b300;
}
nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.currentlink {
  background: #00b300;
}
```

For your HTML, because we can't assign a height to the `<a>`, move `class="currentLink"` to the `<a>`'s parent `<li>` so it looks like the following:

```
<li class="currentlink"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
```

To see it all in action, check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jritchey/pazju8cz/).

Answer (score 0):

It happens because your third `a` text wraps on two lines.
As @dmitry suggested, I'd go with flexbox too. Let's make a few modifications.

First thing, we need `box-sizing: border-box` on our elements and their children

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Next we want the `nav` and the `ul` to be wull width and we apply `display: flex;` to this last one

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Last thing, we need our `a` to cover full height;

```
nav ul li a {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Have a look on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phaberest/5jLcg3wf/1).

Comment: In your fiddle, once the screen is resized to cause the text to wrap, the list items with unwrapped text doing not bear a full colour change when hovered (or assigned the `currentLink` class). There seems to be a height restriction.

Comment: The flex tries to mantain the elements in row till it has enough space for them. For very small screens it would be useful to use a `@media` query and add something like `flex-wrap: wrap;` on the `nav` css

Comment: Agreed - `@media` is a useful tool. I only mentioned the height restriction in your fiddle as it replicates the issue Jordan seems to be trying to resolve. Perhaps he'll now look into `@media` as well as `flex`!

Comment: Thanks so much! Both of these solutions fixed my issue.